# c++ overload resolution and constness

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, overload-resolution

(all tests are performed on Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 19.00.24215.1 for x86)

consider this minimal example:

```
struct myString
{
    operator const char *( ) const { return &dummy; }
    char& operator[]( unsigned int ) { return dummy; }
    const char& operator[]( unsigned int ) const { return dummy; }

    char dummy;
};

int main()
{
    myString str;
    const char myChar = 'a';

    if( str[(int) 0] == myChar ) return 0; //error, multiple valid overloads
}
```

according to overload resolution rules (from cppreference)

> F1 is determined to be a better function than F2 if implicit
>   conversions for all arguments of F1 are not worse than the implicit
>   conversions for all arguments of F2, and
>
> 1) there is at least one
>   argument of F1 whose implicit conversion is better than the
>   corresponding implicit conversion for that argument of F2
>
> 2) or. if
>   not that, (only in context of non-class initialization by conversion),
>   the standard conversion sequence from the return type of F1 to the
>   type being initialized is better than the standard conversion sequence
>   from the return type of F2

`char& operator[]( unsigned int )` should be better, according to 1).

Of the two arguments (this = myString) do not need to be converted at all while `operator const char *( ) const` converts it to const char* and `const char& operator[]( unsigned int ) const` converts it to const myString, therefore there is one argument without any implicit conversion, which happens to be the best conversion

However my compiler yells the following error:

```
1>  [///]\sandbox\sandbox\sandbox.cpp(29): error C2666: 'myString::operator []': 3 overloads have similar conversions
1>  [///]\sandbox\sandbox\sandbox.cpp(19): note: could be 'const char &myString::operator [](unsigned int) const'
1>  [///]\sandbox\sandbox\sandbox.cpp(18): note: or       'char &myString::operator [](unsigned int)'
1>  [///]\sandbox\sandbox\sandbox.cpp(29): note: while trying to match the argument list '(myString, int)'
```

also note that using `if( str[0u] == myChar ) return 0;` or removing `operator const char *( ) const` resolve the error

why is there an error here and what am I getting wrong about overload resolution rules?

edit: it might be a visual C++ bug in this version, any definitive confirmation on this?

Comment: Compile fine with gcc/clang [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f0888ffd8a0d8ce8).

Comment: I am slightly surprised that the compiler claims that there are three candidate overloads, but only mentions two of them.

Comment: Interesting.  I have version 19.10.25019 and it compiles just fine for me.  Might just be a bug they have fixed.

Comment: it's visual C++ compiler, I also took some time to test on clang and it indeed compile fine

Comment: @nathanoliver , it might be a bug in my version maybe, I'll try to check patch notes (edit: if I ever find those)

Comment: compilation result: https://s17.postimg.org/5arxv05db/overload.png

Comment: If you run the code [here](http://rextester.com/l/cpp_online_compiler_visual) which uses Compiler Version 19.00.23506 for x86 it also compiles so it looks even more like a bug.  The code should compile as is.

Comment: Well, I'm still trying to find a patch note about this bug but it seems I'm bad at googling. also using another target toolset, I get the third ambigious overload: `or       'built-in C++ operator[(const char *, int)'`, which is... kinda legitimate? myString -> const char* vs unsigned int -> int. Maybe it has something to do with that?

Comment: it seems like the default operator[] for pointers conflicts with `char& operator[](unsigned int)` which in turn triggers 2) and add `const char& operator[](unsigned int) const` to the list of conflicting overloads. I think it might be a problem with the way pointer [] is implemented in the platform I'm targeting and maybe not directly a problem with the compiler

Comment: Working fine in VS2017 as well, on https://godbolt.org/g/5a8c4T
Is there possibly something in your stdafx.h that's introducing another possible conversion?

Comment: Ah! http://webcompiler.cloudapp.net/ reproduces it, being 19.11.25601.0 (x86). So it seems to vary by compiler version. I haven't seen it reproduce in x64. @NathanOliver reported it didn't reproduce on VS2015 Update 1 on x86, though. Edit: Yeah, that's it. On x64, reproduces with `(long long) 0` instead of `(int) 0`.

Comment: Here's a full set of reproductions. x86_64 on the left, x86 on the right: https://godbolt.org/g/VaihPi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a minified version of the problem, that reproduces on [all compilers I threw at it](https://godbolt.org/g/xnYN7h).

```
#include <stddef.h>

struct myString
{
    operator char *( );
    char& operator[]( unsigned ptrdiff_t );
};

int main()
{
    myString str;
    if( str[(ptrdiff_t) 0] == 'a' ) return 0; //error, multiple valid overloads
}
```

Basically, you have two candidate functions to get the `char` for `bool operator==(char,char)`: [[over.match.oper]/3](http://eel.is/c++draft/over.match.oper#3)

- `char& myString::operator[]( unsigned ptrdiff_t )` ([[over.match.oper]/3.1](http://eel.is/c++draft/over.match.oper#3.1) => [[over.sub]](http://eel.is/c++draft/over.sub))
- `char& operator[]( char*, ptrdiff_t)` ([[over.match.oper]/3.3](http://eel.is/c++draft/over.match.oper#3.3) => [[over.built]/14](http://eel.is/c++draft/over.built#14))

Note that if `myString::operator[]` took a `ptrdiff_t` instead of an `unsigned ptrdiff_t`, then it would have hidden the built-in operator per [[over.built]/1](http://eel.is/c++draft/over.built#1). So if all you want to do is avoid issues like this, simply ensure any `operator[]` overload that takes an integral value, takes a `ptrdiff_t`.

I'll skip the viability check [[over.match.viable]](http://eel.is/c++draft/over.match.viable), and go straight to conversion ranking.

## `char& myString::operator[]( unsigned ptrdiff_t )`

For overloading, this is considered to have a leading implicit object paramter, so the signature to be matched is
`(myString&, unsigned ptrdiff_t)`

### `myString&` => `myString&`

Standard conversion sequence: **[Identity](http://eel.is/c++draft/over.ics.ref#1)** (Rank: *Exact match*) - directly bound reference

### `ptrdiff_t` => `unsigned ptrdiff_t`

Standard conversion sequence: **[Lvalue Transformation](http://eel.is/c++draft/conv.lval) -> [Integral conversion](http://eel.is/c++draft/conv.integral)** (Rank: *Conversion*) - signed lvalue to unsigned prvalue

## `char& operator[]( char*, ptrdiff_t)`

### `myString&` => `char*`

[User-defined conversion sequence](http://eel.is/c++draft/over.ics.user): **[Identity](http://eel.is/c++draft/over.ics.ref#1)** + [`operator char*(myString&)`](http://eel.is/c++draft/class.conv.fct)

Note that per [[over.match.oper]/7](http://eel.is/c++draft/over.match.oper#7) we don't get a second standard conversion sequence.

### `ptrdiff_t` => `ptrdiff_t`

Standard conversion sequence: **Identity** (Rank: *Exact match*)

## [Best viable function](http://eel.is/c++draft/over.match.best)

### First argument

Standard Conversion Sequence is better than User-defined conversion sequence ([[over.ics.rank]/2.1](http://eel.is/c++draft/over.ics.rank#2.1))

### Second argument

Rank Conversion is worse than Rank Exact Match ([[over.ics.rank]/3.2.2](http://eel.is/c++draft/over.ics.rank#3.2.2))

## Result

We cannot satisfy the [requirement](http://eel.is/c++draft/over.match.best#1)

> if for all arguments i, ICSi(F1) is not a worse conversion sequence than ICSi(F2)

so neither function is a better function.

Hence, per [[over.match.best]/2](http://eel.is/c++draft/over.match.best#2) it's **ambiguous**.

---

## How to fix this?

Well, the easiest solution is to **never** let the parameter to an `operator[]` overload be something that could be converted to from `ptrdiff_t` by something other than an *Exact Match*-ranked conversion. Looking at [the conversions table](http://eel.is/c++draft/over.best.ics#tab:over.conversions) that appears to mean that you should always declare your `operator[]` member function as `X& T::operator[]( ptrdiff_t )`. That covers the usual use-case of "Act like an array". As noted above, using precisely `ptrdiff_t` will suppress even *searching* for an `operator T*` candidate by taking the built-in subscript operator off the table.

The other option is to not have both `T1 operator[]` and `operator T2*` defined for the class, where `T1` and `T2` may both fulfill the same parameter of a (possibly implicit) function call. That covers cases where you are using `operator[]` for clever syntactic things, and end up with things like [`T T::operator[](X)`](http://gameangst.com/?p=107). If `X::operator ptrdiff_t()` exists for example, and so does `T::operator T*()`, then you're ambiguous again.

The only use-case for `T::operator T*()` I can imagine is if you want your type to implicitly convert into a pointer to itself, like a function. **Don't do that...**

Comment: Nice investigation!

Comment: Thank you. Once I realised what was going on, I recognised that this is one of the more-common and more-annoying surprise ambiguities: When you have multiple parameters, and your different overloads are each better than the others at one of them. I believe the general solution is "add an overload that matches all the parameters better".